# Seasonal Decomposition

Tags: python, statsmodels

When I decompose a time series using the seasonal decompose method from statsmodels I have the Problem that values are missing on the head/tail of the modelled Data.

This is due to a symmetric moving average approach by default of the seasonal method.

```
    statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose(x, model='additive', filt=None, freq=None, two_sided=True, extrapolate_trend=0)
```

To solve this Problem I have to pass a Filter, but I have no idea so far which one.

Can anyone help me out? It is Important to me to have at least values at the end of my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [the statsmodels documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html):

> *two_sided*: The moving average method used in filtering. If True (default), a centered moving average is computed using the filt. If False, the filter coefficients are for past values only.

*"If False, the filter coefficients are for past values only"*: so it seems that if you were willing to switch to a one-sided filter, you would get all the values at the end of your data, which you say is essential.

Comment: Wow, I must've been very tired to overlook this in the documentation. Thank you very much anyways!

Comment: EDIT: It is also possible by setting the "extrapolate_trend" paramter from 0 to 1 e.g. to get the model filled in both directions. Just as an info for others.